# cakePHP form button without submit

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I got these buttons inside a form which I want to NOT trigger a submit, they are simple html buttons

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Point'); ?>
...
<button class="btn">text</button> => this one shouldn't trigger a submit
...
<?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'add', 'div' => false, 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-block')); ?>
```

however cakephp always handles these as submits, just as the regular form end buttons. Any way to prevent this?

I tried using jquery

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But that won't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<button type="button" class="btn">text</button>
```

instead.

The default `type` for button is `submit`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create [simple button](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::button) instead of a [submit button](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::submit). If you put arguments inside `$this->Form-end()` you'll get a submit button by default. But you could easily add extra buttons (with no function attached by default) and end the Form without a submit button.

Something like this should do

```
echo $this->Form->button('A button', 
                         array('class' => 'btn'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Also, check other type of action-trigger buttons, like [postButton](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postButton) and [postLink](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink), meybe those fit better for what you want to do instead of preventing default functions of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Check It...

```
$('.btn').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});
```

OR

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```